# Is it safe to remove !important flags from .hidden in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a bootstrap theme in Elgg, and one of the issues I am running against is that both use `.hidden` CSS class.
Bootstrap is rather overbearing setting `display` and `visibility` to none/hidden with `!important` flag, where as in Elgg `.hidden` is used a lot to initial hide an element and then toggle its visiblity with jQuery `$.show()`. Obviously that causes problems with bootstrap's rules.
What does bootstrap use `.hidden` for and is it safe to set the rule to `display: none` without all the paranoid stuff?

Comment: try it and see. !important causes it to be more specific than all other cases that don't use !important, if that isn't a problem then there's no problem removing it.

Comment: Well, it's a mish mash of two themes, so I am not really sure if I am breaking anything until there is a hick up. The question is why Bootstrap is so strict? Is it used mostly for JS bindings?

Comment: if it didn't use !important, `.hidden` wouldn't be specific enough to override `.something .else { display: block; visibility: visible;}` The real question is... is that actually a problem in your case, and that depends entirely on your application.

Comment: @KevinB good point.

Comment: I guess I won't know until I have gone through all of the UI. I am just starting on this large project that's been going on for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest modifying the Bootstrap CSS.

Alternatively, you could use `.toggleClass(".hidden")`, rather than toggling the display of elements with the `.show()` function.

Comment: It's a common patter in Elgg to `$.toggle()` and I am dealing with a project with a few dozen plugins. I would rather not go and modify a ton of JS if I can override a CSS rule.

Comment: We have an open ticket floating around to namespace these commons classes in Elgg, but it's a headache as you can imagine. So, I will just keep fingers crossed ;)

Comment: I've seen many discussions about it on the twbs Github account. The consensus is that people would prefer that the hidden class did not have !important, but @KevinB does have a good point about nested classes taking precedence.

Comment: I'm sure you're not the only person to have ever used Bootstrap and Elgg together. Hopefully you can get somewhere with Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite `$.toggle` to also toggle the `hidden` class like so:

```
$.fn.toggle = function (state) {
  state = state || !this.is(':visible');
  return this.toggleClass('hidden', state).toggle(state);
};
```